# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on plugins page

Tags: fatal-error

I have just migrated my localhost WordPress site to my live server using the [this tutorial](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/).

For some reason, when I try to activate ANY plugin from within WordPress, it gives me the following error message:

'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /var/sites/d/sitename.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/elementor/elementor.php on line 55'

Can anyone give me advice as to why this is happening please?

Comment: Your PHP version might be too old. Make sure you are running PHP 7, that's the current standard.

Comment: What is in that file around line 55?

Comment: @janh2 I’ve seen this before, it’s an anonymous function, so won’t work below PHP 5.3.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone - this was it! Stupid question maybe, but at least I know for next time! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're running an outdated PHP version (lower than 5.3)? You should update the PHP on your server. Best case to PHP 7+